# How to find villages in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do villages spawn in Minecraft Pocket Edition? I would also like to know what I need to do to have a village spawn, e.g., if there is any specific biome it has to be in.

Answer (score 7):

Villagers and villages were added in the 0.9.0 update. If you just want to create a new world with a village in it, you can use the seed 1409511342. You should spawn right next to a village. I believe every generated world will have at least one village in it. Sometimes they may be nearby, or they could be far, far away.

If, however, you want to get a village in a world you have already created, you should be able to find one after adventuring for a while UNLESS the world was created pre-0.9.0. In that case, you should be able to use MCEdit (a PC program) to copy a village from a PC world and place it in your PE world. It's pretty straightforward to use MCEdit, but if your world is 0.9.0+, you shouldn't need to use it.

Comment: I have 1424211818 seed and dropped right next to one as well.

Answer (score -2):

They are adding villagers in 0.9.0 so there will be villages as well

You can always make your own like mine
[image]

Comment: 1 dislike because you said you can make your own but that has nothing to do with spawned villages.