# Are there generated structures in Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Are there any type of generated structures, such as dungeons, witch huts, temples, villages or caves, in Minecraft Pocket Edition? I'm asking especially about version 0.8.1 alpha.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Arqade! I've edited your question as an attempt to make it more clear. If the meaning of the post changed (if I understood you incorrectly), you should rollback the edit from the "edited" link. I don't know the answer myself, but someone else should now be able to answer.

Comment: @Jose This is a site where people ask for help, then they wait patiently for someone to see their question and answer it.  Given that you waited exactly 4 minutes before posting a comment demanding attention, I'm not certain you understood the way the site works.  Please take the time to read the tour located under the help tab above.

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/153622/how-to-spawn-minecraft-villages)

Answer (score 1):

Not yet but there will be an update which will turn the answer to a yes.
Additions include villages, caves, lava pools & mineshafts. I heard it comes out on 29.6.14 but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Now, with the recent 0.9.0 update, yes, there are generated structures. These include,

- Villages, do note, villagers are not able to be traded with.
- Mineshafts, which often come with goodies in minecarts. Watch out for spider spawners though.
- Stongholds, do note, strongholds are just there to be there, the end and nether are not in the game yet.
- Dungeons, which can spawn a variety of monsters, including, creepers, skeletons, zombies.
- Temples, temples spawn in deserts and jungles, and both contain dangerous traps, but with goodies loaded inside.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**No.** As of version 0.8.1 alpha, there are no generated structures of any kind in Pocket Edition. According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_upcoming_features#0.9.0), generated structures are planned for 0.9.0 alpha.

Answer (score -1):

Not really there can sometimes be lava falls and water falls generated maybe big overhangs that are good for mining but no generated structures are in the current versions yet but in 0.9.0 mojang are adding caves,lava pools and mineshaft s in pe as generated structures